# How to Handle two listviews in one activity?

Tags: android, listview

In my application,im using two listviews and both are not showing simultaneously.But im using the same "custom adapter class".But it is showing different results while implementing pagination.Pagination works well in the first listview which loads initially.But when i click another listview to show the results,it is not working

My Problem: How to implement pagination in both of these listviews effectively?Is it better to use two  different custom adapter class?

Here the sample code which i done for pagination------

```
            btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TotalPages = TotalPages + 1;
            if (pagenum == 0) {

                            btnPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pagenum = pagenum + 1;
                }
                else {

    recentCracks = web.getAllRecentCrackUps(pagenum);
            if (recentCracks != null) {
    adapter = new DynamicListAdapter(KidsCrackMeUp.this, recentCracks);
        lstRecentPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                        txtPageCount.setText(String.valueOf(pagenum));
                        txtTotalPages.setText(String.valueOf(totalpagecount));
                    }
        if (pagenum == 1) {
                            //btnPrev.setEnabled(false);
                            btnPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

//Button Previous Ends Here-----------

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
        pagenum = pagenum + 1;
                        btnPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TotalPages = TotalPages - 1;
            //btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
                if (TotalPages == 0) {
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                pagenum = pagenum - 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                recentCracks = web.getAllRecentCrackUps(pagenum);
                if (recentCracks != null)
                  {
            adapter = new DynamicListAdapter(KidsCrackMeUp.this, recentCracks);
            lstRecentPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
                     }
                        txtPageCount.setText(String.valueOf(pagenum));
                        txtTotalPages.setText(String.valueOf(totalpagecount));
                    }
                if (TotalPages == 1) {
        **strong text**//   btnNext.setEnabled(false);
                            btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

//Button Next Ends Here----

```
            }

            else

            {
                btnNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            // rel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            lstRecentPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your question.I didnt get anything from it.
if you are trying to display two separate lists of same type then i would suggest you to go with SeparatedListAdapter